# Android app where I can create custom Yoga routines and search through custom routines created by other users

Tags: android, health, fitness

I need an Android app where I can customize a yoga routine. I've searched through several apps but have not found anything which has this functionality. I need:

- An app which allows me to create my own yoga routine (paid or free doesn't matter) - this means a set of exercises + reps
- If the app can have a timer then that's a bonus (like holding X for 30 seconds so it has a countdown timer for it)
- And preferably the app should have a feature to share different yoga routines with the community

A very similar app is "Jefit" fitness tracker but it doesn't have options for yoga routines. It's only for gym routines.